# Spring Boot + React: reload application tabs when data has been posted to the server on one of the tabs

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring

I'm making a Spring Boot + React application.

Let's say I opened **2 identical tabs** with *Update Employee* component: [like on a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Rgu.png)

I made some changes on one of the tabs. I sent data to the server by clicking *Save* button.

The problem is that I don't want to let user go to the second tab with old data loaded on the form. The user might click *Save* an the old data will override recently posted data. And therefore no changes will be made.

**What is a mechanism to reload/rerender all the other tabs after data has been posted to the server on one of the tabs?** So there will be the actual data shown everywhere.

Or are there some patterns to do it in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will be solved with using `optimistic locking` and `versioning` your entities in the database.
If you're using `jpa` please refer to this post

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking